# httpHandler in ASP.NET MVC 5.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, httphandler

My `RouteConfig.cs`

```
public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allasmx}", new { allasmx = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc= @".*\.svc(/.*)?" });
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allFileAttachments}", new { allattachment = @".*\file.attachment(/.*)?" });
            ...
            ...
            ...
       }
   }
```

Web.config

```
<configuration>
....
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
 <add path="*.attachment" verb="*" type="MyType, Namespace" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
<remove name="attachmentHandler" />
      <add name="attachmentHandler" verb="*" path="*.attachment" type="myType, namespace" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
...
</system.webServer>
...
</configuration>
```

When I try accessing the following URL, it still tries to find a controller and fails with 404

> http://localhost/somepath/file.attachment?4535345343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved the issue.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
   <add name="attachmentHandler"  verb="*" 
                 path="*.attachment" 
                 type="myType, namespace" 
                 resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
...
</system.webServer>
```

Reference [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx) - **To register an HTTP handler for IIS 7.0 running in Integrated Mode**